# AWS API Gateway Compressed Response

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I understand as of November 2016 API Gateway now supports binary media types.  Is it possible to return compressed HTTP from a lambda proxy?

I have an express js application that needs return compressed output (from a database query), otherwise the response body exceeds the lambda response body limit.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, API Gateway does not currently support HTTP compression. However, it is in consideration for future development. And Passing binary output from Lambda to API Gateway is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return compressed data in base64 encoded String from Lambda to API Gateway.

Then you can use the binary media types feature to convert the base64 encoded String back to binary data before returning to the client.

If you want to force API Gateway to return binary data instead of respecting the accept header, you can set the contentHandling property in the integration response to *CONVENT_TO_BINARY* via CLI.

```
aws apigateway update-integration-response \
    --rest-api-id <api-id> \
    --resource-id <resource-id> \
    --http-method GET \
    --status-code 200 \
    --patch-operations '[{"op" : "replace", "path" : "/contentHandling", "value" : "CONVERT_TO_BINARY"}]'
```

[See example of binary support with Lambda.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-lambda.html)

Comment: Thanks.  So if I have a json string that I gzip (content-type: application/json, content-encoding: gzip), and send this as a base64 encoded string, will API Gateway be able to translate this back into binary and pass it onto my client?

Comment: API Gateway will not unzip your data and pass it to your client. Your client will need to know how to deal with gzip data.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to hack up a way to decode/ungzip on the client, but this worked.

Comment: @galacticpresident Can you walk through how you managed to do that. Great if you could post your serverless response object here

Comment: @CharithW I used pako - this is the line of code on the client:
var decodedData = JSON.parse(pako.inflate(atob(data), { to: 'string'}));

Performance is not ideal for large result sets.  I really need to figure out a streaming result solution.